# Запись данных из текстового файла в целочисленный массив С++

Tags: c++

есть текстовый файл ("Data.txt"), в котором данные о двух работниках - имя, фамилия, дата рождения и далее до конца строки количество часов, которые работал в день работник в течении месяца. Файл "Data.txt":

```
Jonaitis Jonas 19190101 5 6 8 8 9 0 0 9 8 6 4 7 0 0 6 8 7 9 5 0 0 6 9 7 5 4 0 0 8 5 7
Petraitis Petras 19111111 7 7 8 8 9 0 0 9 8 6 4 7 0 0 6 8 7 9 6 0 0 6 9 7 5 5 0 0 8 11 6
```

Я написала код, который должен подсчитывать количество часов и сверхурочное время и выводить в файл "Results.txt" следующие данные: фамилия, имя, дата рождения, часы, сверхурочное время. Но результат не радует...

Файл с кодом "main.cpp":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream fd ("Data.txt");
    ofstream fr ("Results.txt");

    char name, surname, date_of_birth, text[256];
    int num, hours, overhours;
    while(!fd.eof())
    {
        hours=0;
        overhours=0;
        fd >> name >> surname >> date_of_birth;
        fd.getline(text, 255);
        fr << name << " " << surname << " " << date_of_birth;
        for (int i=0; i<31; i++)
        {
            num = (int)text[i];
            if(num <=8)
            {
                hours += num;
            }
            else
            {
                hours += 8;
                overhours += 8-num;
            }
        }
        fr << hours << " " << overhours;

    }

    fd.close();
    fr.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Файл с результатом "Results.txt":

```
J o n248 -1735P e t248 -1873P e t240 -1767
```

Comment: `char name`? Один-единственный символ? Каким это образом вы собираетесь поместить целое имя сотрудника в **один** символ??? `num = (int)text[i];` - что вы пытаетесь сделать здесь?

Comment: Я бы при помощи fprintf и fscanf записывал и читал, такой формат данных в текстовых файлах.

Answer (score 0):

Поехали, Ваши ошибки :

1) char name, surname, date_of_birth, text[256]; - вы в char кладете char * - плохо..

2) overhours += 8-num; - надо из часов вычитать норму, а то у вас отрицательный ответ будет.

3) fd.getline(text, 255); - зачем ?????

После исправления данных ошибок получим следующий код -

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string> 
#include <vector>
#include <sstream> 


int main()
{
    std::ifstream fd ("Data.txt");
    std::ofstream fr ("Results.txt");    

    while(!fd.eof())
    {
        std::string name, surname, date_of_birth, text;
        int hours{0};
        int overhours{0};
        fd >> name >> surname >> date_of_birth;
        std::getline(fd,text);

        fr << name << " " << surname << " " << date_of_birth << " ";

        std::vector<int> h_vec;

        std::stringstream ss{text};
        int n{0};
        while (ss >> n) {
             h_vec.push_back(n);
        }

        for (auto v : h_vec) {
            if (v < 0) {
                throw std::runtime_error("time less that zero");
            }
            if (v <= 8) {
                hours += v;
            } else {
                hours += 8;
                overhours += (v - 8);
            }
        }
        fr << hours << " " << overhours << '\n';
    }

    fd.close();
    fr.close();
    return 0;
}
```